# rails 3.1 - moving data from local data processing server to heroku production server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building a rails 3.1 app that requires a load of data to be crunched and processed on a local server (using a bunch of non-rails tools and writing to mysql) and then for the refined results to be punted up to a heroku production server (front end). because the data crunching aspect of the process needs to be run in batches, my first instinct was simply to upload the results table to production using something like "heroku db:push --tables data" - but the problem is that it is sslloowww and the app is without data for about 40mins at a time. the crunching batches need to be run about 4x per day - so it looks like this approach isn't really going to work. any suggestions how to speed this process up or any alternative schemes for getting the data less obtrusively up to the production server? thanks!

Comment: How much data needs to be uploaded? Does it all have to go at once, or is your data generated in smaller chunks?

Comment: hi - in total it's about about 1m records. The data needs to be calculated in batches, but they don't necessarily need to be uploaded to heroku in one go (they could be drip-fed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you may have to rearchitect or what about running your rails app on EC2 and ditching Heroku?  I think Heroku is great if your app is simple or you can make do with the plugins that they have.  But when it gets complex I think it may be too complicated.

Heroku makes it clear that you cannot access their databases from outside.  What you can do however is (if you want to stay on Heroku) is to use another database (like the RDS or roll your own) and have your application connect to it.  Then upload data to that database directly.